# Rails: how do I use question marks in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, model, mongoid

We have a field in our mongodb database called "failed?", including the question mark. Sometimes when I access that field, I get the value in the database, and sometimes I get null. I'm looking to understand what should happen a little bit more in order to debug this. So, can you have a question mark in a field name in a model, like so:

```
field :failed?, :type => Boolean, :default => nil
```

or am I in for a world of trouble. Assuming I already have this in the database and have to work with it, how should I get the fields out.

Environment: Rails 3.1, JRuby, Mongoid.

Comment: Interesting. I personally would never use question mark notation for a field name :-)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: of course, but that was not the question :) They're added by another process, so we are stuck with them for now.

Comment: Well, can't help you here. Will wait for an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely a Mongoid bug as question marks in field names are valid in MongoDB. If I had to take a guess, it could be a weird conflict with the automatic `<field>?` that are created by Mongoid.

The easiest way to work around this would be to try accessing it through the raw hash that is pulled out from MongoDB, you can access it with `model.attributes["failed?"]`. If you still have issues, then likely it's a MongoDB driver problem.